# React Native, deployed the environment

Tags: react-native

React-Native.
Errors when starting the project, help me figure it out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXtvC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eOvA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNz78.png)

Picture №4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SYGW.png)

Picture №5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAlCE.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please write your question in english, thank you!

Comment: @simo54, Hello. Everything is ready.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac or Linux?

Comment: @Gavin D'mello, windows

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your first issue: It appears like your android environment is not set!

Run this command before you execute any build commands:

```
cd routeToProjectDirectory
```

Then run these commands:

> To clear any cache or old build data

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
```

> To set environment for android on MacOS

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

For setting up environment on windows for android, follow this [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

**Once** the environment setup issue is resolved, go ahead and run this command to run your project:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

These steps are the basics for running a new react-native project and hopefully this solution solves your issue.

If not, drop me a message and I can help you figure it out over a call or so. Happy to help!

Comment: I did it according to the instructions, but the errors are the same

Comment: Thanks, everything seems to have started, but there are some errors. It seems to me they are connected with Node 17, I probably need to downgrade the Node version, can you tell me?

Comment: Look at the 4th and 5th picture please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Everything works, I installed Node 16.13.0.

Comment: Good to know that things work now.  Could you mark my answer as the solution to your problem @Vadim